# I can't install any package. Showing this issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, lumen

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- noitran/opendox v0.1.0 requires illuminate/routing ~5.7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.7.0, ..., v5.8.36].
- noitran/opendox v1.0.0 requires illuminate/routing ^5|^6|^7|^8 -> satisfiable by illuminate/routing[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36,
v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6, v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27].
- illuminate/routing[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.33] require illuminate/container 5.0.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.33] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.1.1, ..., v5.1.41] require illuminate/container 5.1.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.1.1, ..., v5.1.41] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.45] require illuminate/container 5.2.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.2.0, ..., v5.2.45] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.2.25, ..., v5.3.23] require illuminate/container 5.3.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.3.0, v5.3.4, v5.3.16, v5.3.23] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match.
Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] require illuminate/container 5.4.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.44] require illuminate/container 5.5.* -> found illuminate/container[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.44] but the package is fixed to v10.6.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- illuminate/routing[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.36] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.    - illuminate/routing[v6.0.0, ..., v6.19.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
- illuminate/routing[v6.20.0, ..., v6.20.44] require illuminate/container ^6.0 -> found illuminate/container[v6.0.0, ..., v6 versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require noitran/opendox:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require noitran/opendox:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

I'm tried to fix this issue anyone kinly help me

Comment: did you run `composer install`?

Comment: Yes. I did @Jack

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is detailed in the error message:

> require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

It's written multiple times in the message.

The `composer` has been executed with php v8.2 when your project needs php v7.2 or higher BUT lower than v8.0.
Try to downgrade the php version you use to match the requirements! :)